# "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" on very simple Laravel + Vue app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm starting to get into using Laravel with Vue and following along a tutorial until I got this error. It seems like Vue is stuck in a recursive loop somewhere trying to load components (I think) but I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing it and other similar error messages answers I searched for online were no help in my case.

I have two Vue components:

Articles.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Articles</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

Navbar.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-info mb-2">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                Articles
            </a>
        </div>
    </navbar>
</div>
</template>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue').default);
Vue.component('articles', require('./components/Articles.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<body>
        <div id="app">
            <navbar></navbar>
            <div class="container">
                <articles></articles>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}">
</script>
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

I'm following a tutorial from 2018 so it might be outdated. But could someone please indicate what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I've noticed if I change

```
Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue').default);
```

to

```
Vue.component('vue-nav', require('./components/Navbar.vue').default);
```

it works, although I don't know why. Does it have something to do with Bootstrap perhaps?

Comment: cant tell from the code you gave, looks alright to me. Whats in your `./bootstrap` file?

Comment: @Flame I've updated my question with the bootstrap.js content, minus the default comments. It's default since I haven't added or changed anything inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `Navbar.vue`. You've got this:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <navbar class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-info mb-2">
```

That's trying to use a `navbar` component inside a `navbar` component.

Changing `Vue.component('navbar'` to `Vue.component('vue-nav',` will prevent the infinite recursion because the `<navbar>` tag no longer refers to the `Navbar` component. However, this isn't a real fix, you just need to change the `<navbar>` to the appropriate component. I don't know what that's supposed to be but just a `<nav>` may suffice for now.

```html
<template>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-info mb-2">
```

Comment: Thank you. I also just noticed it was a typo that emmet automatically put in using Navbar instead of Nav. Doh!